# spell check in Google Chrome on windows

Tags: google-chrome

How to enable automatic Arabic spell check in google chrome ? I couldn't do it by editing the chrome settings . Is there any packages to be added externally or can i edit it in chrome settings.

Answer (score 0):

Arabic spellcheck is not available for **Chrome** at the moment, but it is available for **Firefox**, you can add it from Mozilla add-ons: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/arabic-spell-checking-dictiona/

[image: Arabic spell check for FireFox]